# Date Filter Views As a select box instead of text field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

When using the date filter in the views module, is it possible to have a select list or a nice date popup instead of just a text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exact way in drupal 7 but i'm giving you an example how you can do this in drupal 6 and simulate the same process in drupal 7.

If you have a Date Popup module installed in your site that you can find under module date package. if not then use jquery_ui module and install it.

```
      In view filter 

        1] click on + sing then select date from dropdown 
        2] choose node or user according to your need 
        3] after that you will find section "Date form type:" select popup radio button 
        4] whatever date field you require from "Date field(s): checkbox" 

that's it.
```

Comment: Thanks, the only trick I had to do that you didn't mention was enable Views --> Date Views

Answer (score 0):

you can do by using form overridings in drupal it is flexible...

please refer to http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6